# File upload with nodejs, express and angular using dropzone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm having trouble getting the file recognized server side with node.

Specifically when accessing request data, (req.files or req.body)

Here are some snippets if someone has any advice.

**html**:

```
<form action="/upload" class="dropzone" drop-zone id="file-dropzone"></form>
```

**angular controller**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .controller('SampleCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


  })

  .directive('dropZone', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
     $(element).dropzone({ 
        url: "/upload",
        maxFilesize: 100,
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 5
    });
  }
});
```

**node router**:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./import.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', controller.import);

module.exports = router;
```

**node controller**:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

exports.import = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files); // responds with 'undefined'
    console.log(req.body); // responds with {}
};
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You're adding the **multer** middleware to the `app` in your controller. I don't think it is doing what you expect it to as  `exports.import` has no connection to `app`.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same issue, did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

You have to actually use the file upload middleware to get express to unpack that part of the request.  From the `multer` docs:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')

var app = express()
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));

console.log(req.body)
console.log(req.files)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately adding app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'})); still gives me the same responses.